# How close menu from ionic 5

Tags: menu, ionic5

I have a simple question but I cant't find a solution.
I created a new project in Ionic 5 and I use "sidemenu" template.
From documentation I read that close method should close the menu.
I put in the constructor "public menuCtrl: MenuController" and in ngOnInit:

this.menuCtrl.close();

but nothing works. From debug I see menuCtrl empty....
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `MenuController` is in your top level app.component page not in the individual page so you would need to write the code inside `app.component.ts`.

Alternatively you can automate it by wrapping each menu item in a `ion-menu-toggle` like:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="true" *ngFor="let page of navigate">
      <ion-item [routerLink]="page.url" routerDirection="forward">
        <ion-icon [name]="page.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        {{ page.title }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-menu-toggle>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Hi, I did so in the app.component.ts:
~~~lang-js

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuctrl.close();
    ...
  }

~~~
after import "private menuctrl: MenuController" in the contrusctor with "import {MenuController} from '@ionic/angular';" at the top.
But it doesn't work